# Netbook Remix goes to low graphics mode after booting up from hibernate

Tags: 10.04, video, ubuntu-netbook, graphics, hibernate

I am using an Asus 1005P netbook. What happens is when I wake up the machine from hibernate state, a while later x crashes and goes to low graphics mode.

I stumbled on solutions in ubuntuforums but none of them seem to work:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1498447

Does anyone have another solution for this?

Comment: I have this issue too, and it doesn't appear to me to be specifically due to being a netbook. My Acer eMachines E525 laptop has an attached display, so I'm in dual-screen display. If I boot without the display, it comes out of hibernate clean. If I boot with the display, the hibernation has the same issue as you. I have to logout and back in again for the display to be corrected. I would like to see a fix as well.

Answer (score 2):

This most likely is a bug. If you want to debug and collect information that could explain why it doesn't work on your laptop, take a look at [The Ubuntu wiki page on debugging low power states](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspendHibernateResume).